# How to replace index value in mutableListOf?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to replace middle 0 with 1. How can I do it?

```
val list = mutableListOf(0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: `mutableListOf(0,0,1,0,0)` :)

Comment: Ok, thanks:), if I want to use `list` variable to do it?

Comment: @vasik988 if my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
val list = mutableListOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
list[list.size / 2] = 1
// after this array should look like this: (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
val list = mutableListOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
list[list.size / 2] = 1
```

**Assumption:** list size would be odd number

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean? List size is 5. Is it important if it's odd or not?

Comment: Or maybe size is 4.

Comment: If the size is 4, then it isn't clear what you want to replace from the question.

Comment: I see, so index is counting from 0 and size is counting from 1 as I understand.